# Não consigo renderizar elementos dinamicamente usando forEach

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, react-navigation

Gostaria de saber se tem como renderizar o componente `Drawer.Screen` dentro de `Drawer.Navigator`, de forma dinâmica. Tentei fazer colocando os componentes em um array (materias/index.js) e percorre-los com `.forEach()`, como mostrado em Routes/index.js. Porém, ao clicar em qualquer uma das páginas, gera o seguinte erro:

```
"The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Matematica"} was not handled by any navigator."
```

Ou seja, não renderizou.

Materias/index.js:

```js
import Matematica from '~/pages/materias/Matematica';
import Portugues from '~/pages/materias/Portugues';
import Fisica from '~/pages/materias/Fisica';

export default function Materias() {
  return [
    { name: 'Matematica', component: Matematica },
    { name: 'Portugues', component: Portugues },
    { name: 'Fisica', component: Fisica },
  ];
}
```

Routes/index.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import HomePage from '~/pages/HomePage';
import Materias from '~/pages/materias'

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function DrawerNavigation({ navigation }) { 

    const materias = Materias();

    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator
          initialRouteName="HomePage"
          drawerContent={() => ...}
        >
        
        <Drawer.Screen
          name="HomePage"
          component={HomePage}
          options={...}
        />
        
        {/* Lugar que gera o erro */}
        {materias.forEach((element) => (
          <Drawer.Screen
            name={element.name}
            component={element.component}
            options={...}
          />
        ))}

        </Drawer.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `.forEach()` vs `.map()`

Quando desejar exibir algum tipo de lista num componente em React, use o [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), pois além da função desejada ser executada, é retornado um resultado para cada elemento do Array. O [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) apenas executa a função e não retorna um valor.

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

console.log('Retorno do .forEach():',  arr.forEach(el => el));
console.log('Retorno do .map():',  arr.map(el => el));
```

#### Renderizando listas no React

Sendo ainda mais específico, os componentes retornados dentro do `.map()` devem possuir uma `key`. Veja na documentação [Listas e Chaves](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

> As chaves ajudam o React a identificar quais itens sofreram alterações, foram adicionados ou removidos. As chaves devem ser atribuídas aos elementos dentro do array para dar uma identidade estável aos elementos.

O código poderia ficar assim:

```js
{materias.forEach((element) => (
  <Drawer.Screen
    key={element.name} {/* Identificador */}
    name={element.name}
    component={element.component}
    options={...}
  />
))}
```